# How do I create a HORIZONTAL menu in a CGI Perl program?

Tags: html

I have a CGI page `Login.cgi` with a form where I need to enter the valid password and it would then redirect to another page called `Main.cgi`. In this page I want a **HORIZONTAL menu** with *UsersList*, *Logs*, *Logout* etc. like the menu on this page with *Questions*, *Tags*, *Users* etc. When I point the mouse on it then it should give the list of users like it gives in a dropdown list when we click it.

I am using Apache 2.2, CGI 1.1 and ActivePerl and I am using a SQLite DB on Windows XP platform. I am new to this CGI Perl programming so please do help me out, provide me any links which might help me, or any websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good beginning introduction to CGI and perl is [Ovid's CGI Course](http://jdporter.perlmonk.org/cgi_course/)