# How to create vertical main menu with horizontal sub menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create vertical main menu with horizontal sub menu.

Item 1

Item 2_ Item2_1  Item2_2 Item2_3

Item 3

Item 4

In this manner how can i create such menu.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: SO is not your personal CSS machine.
There are plenty of resources online that tell you exactly how to make this, if you take the minimal effort of searching for it.

Comment: Duplicate of? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751998/how-can-i-create-a-horizontal-html-menu-with-a-vertical-submenu-using-css-only or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893900/how-to-add-vertical-sub-menu-to-horizontal-menu-using-css-and-html

Answer (score 2):

I have this code for you, it's an complete implementation including jQuery for touch ability.

Here is also a [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/julian_weinert/ds8J3/) for demonstration.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="doubletaptogo.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { console.log('ready'); $('li:has(ul)').doubleTapToGo();});
    </script>
    <style>
        * {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        body * {
            display:block;
        }
        ul li {
            width:200px;
            height:100px;

            float:left;
            position:relative;

            background-color:red;
        }
        ul li ul {
            top:100px;
            left:0px;
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
        }
        ul li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
        }
        ul li ul li {
            position:relative;
            background-color:green;
        }
        ul li ul li ul {
            top:0px;
            left:200px;
            width:10000px;
        }
        ul li ul li ul li {
            float:left;
            position:relative;
            background-color:blue;
        }
        ul li ul li ul li ul {
            top:100px;
            left:0px;
            width:200px;
        }
        ul li ul li ul li ul li {
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        ul li ul li ul li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                test 1
            </li>
            <li>
                test 1
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        test 2.1
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                test 2.1
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                test 3.2
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        test 2.2
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                test 3.1
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                test 3.2
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        test 3.1
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        test 3.2
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can try to make a simple and default list!

And inside each list item, create a new list, but this time use this:

```
ul.child li {
  display: inline;
}
```

And to show them, you can use jQuery's API.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Superfish Menu.

I have always used it. After you get it . Then its a matter of editing it to suite your needs.

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/vertical/